# Screen tearing on an external monitor with NVIDIA RTX 3070

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

I’ve got a Lenovo Legion 5 Pro and I use an external monitor. I’m experiencing horizontal screen tearing when I scroll down/up and when I watch movies or youtube videos. This does not happen when I use the laptop’s screen. The external monitor is connected to the HDMI port.

```
System info:
AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics
NVIDIA RTX 3070 with Nvidia 470
Kernel 5.11.0-34-generic #36~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 27 08:06:32 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I’ve got my system set to Nvidia Performance mode. If I set Power saving mode the monitor is not detected. If I set Nvidia On Demand, graphical performance on the external monitor slows to a crawl.

I’m looking for a solution for eliminating the screen tearing on the external monitor. It doesn’t matter if that solution switches off the Nvidia graphics card or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Enabling "Force Full Composition Pipeline" eliminates screen tearing on the second screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop and I experienced a similar problem after I upgraded the kernel. To solve it, I downgraded the kernel to `5.11.0-31-generic` (if you don't have it, install it with `apt install linux-headers-5.11.0-31-generic` (I'm not sure if you need to install some other things as well, like `linux-image-5.11.0-31-generic`, or if it will happen automatically).

Other things to make sure:

1. For met the external monitor works best with the nvidia propietary drivers and in the "Nvidia on-demand" setting
2. Make sure you select the *Dynamic* graphics mode in the bios (press F2 on start-up. I had to update the bios before that option showed up)
3. I used [this redit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/mmptqi/lenovo_legion_5_ubuntu_2004_final_guide_dream/) for my setup. I didn't have to add the PPA for a new kernel, because I'm on 21.04, but here are some quotes that helped me:

   - *In the BIOS (F2 at lenovo screen) must set to HYBRID mode* (now renamed to dynamic graphics mode, I think)
   - *edit grub and add the entry amdgpu.backlight=0* to fix backlight control of the original monitor
   - *Tip: Gnome users can use this extension to change nvidia or integrated mode easy: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1275/prime-indicator/*

Comment: On a side note: the only problem I still have is that some applications (I think *electron* applications like the Element and Rocket.Chat desktop apps) are super slow on the external monitor but not on the internal monitor. This really freaks me out.

I also noticed that fractional scaling is not (yet) supported if you use the "Nvidia only" mode.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but it didn't work. Nvidia on demand causes poor performance in the second monitor. I do not have brightness control issues on my machine with the current drivers and kernel version.